# Bootstrap ajax modal on slow internet conncetion causes old data to be visible shortly

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code to display AJAX generated data in a Bootstrap modal

`<a data-remote="false" href="https://www.mydomain.nl/app/index.php/tasks/show/605" data-proposal-id="605" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal">Show data</a>`

This works fine, however when loading a second one, on a short internet connection it shows the old content from the first call before showing the new data. This only happens on a slow internet connection, assuming it immediately launches the modal, even before the AJAX request is finished.

Is there anyway to delay the pop-up being shown until the new data has been loaded?

Comment: You should add you AJAX code here. You should use ev.preventDefault(); on button which shows you modal and you should bind loading ajax data on that button and on success just show your modal with $("#ModalName").modal("show");

Comment: Its also nice to have timeout here with error and some kind of loading wheel so user knows sth is going on.

Comment: @RaV this is bootstraps default way to handle AJAX loaded modals. There is no other code other than including bootstrap.min.js

Comment: _"Is there anyway to delay the pop-up being shown until the new data has been loaded?"_ - not if you want to stick to default functionality. But you could try and _empty_ the modal the moment it is shown (or write placeholder content or a loading indicator to it), by specifying a handler for the `show.bs.modal` event, that _"fires immediately when the show instance method is called"_ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events